# How to package the cassandra source code into debian package?

Tags: debian, cassandra, packaging

I have the latest source code of Cassandra.

I have done some changes to the cassandra code to meet my needs.

Now I want to package this Cassandra into the **debian** package so that I can easily install it.

I do not have much knowledge about debian and all.
Can anyone explain the step by step procedure for the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you already have all the build dependencies, all you need to do is run this command from the Cassandra root directory:

```
$ dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
```

It is strongly recommended that you build it with the OracleJDK instead of OpenJDK. There is a bug with certain versions of OpenJDK that will cause the build to fail.

All of this information is [available on the Cassandra Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DebianPackaging#Building_Packages_on_Debian).